# How to get real world location from a 360 degree panoramic image based on the selected pixel value?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, lidar, 360-panorama

I have been working on this problem wherein if I select a random point in a Pano image, I need to get the real world coordinate value of that. The Inputs that I have are

[image: Input]

where X, Y and Z are in meters.

[image: The Input image are images like this:]

I have tried using the conventional formulae that are mentioned in [this](https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/202559089-How-are-the-Internal-and-External-Camera-Parameters-defined). But those formulae don't work here. The focal length of the camera is 8mm.

I am also working on an alternate method where I am trying to map that Pano image onto the trajectory LiDAR LAS file. I have the LiDAR data containing the entire stretch of the road along with the XYZ coordinates mentioned above. Based on the [paper](https://sci-hub.se/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9090401) that I have read, they mention on using feature extraction to get the keypoints and map it on top of the other. I am still looking for methods on how to do it.

The main purpose of this is to select an object on the image and get its real world coordinate and I have been trying both ways to get it. Any push towards the right direction would be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.